# Ubuntu 13.10 64Bit version only shows 2.9GB of Ram

Tags: ram

I have an old PC at home with 1.5 GB of RAM and as expected its quite slow.

So I decided to install Ubuntu on a different PC. Intel Quad Core and 4 GB of memory, and a graphic card with dedicated memory. I installed the 64 bit version.

I also notice its much slower that running Windows 7 (that was unexpected) and Ubuntu only seems to recognize 2.9 GB.

Ive been searching this forum, I see chat about bad memory and installing 32 bit version. I've run memtest and no errors there. I've made sure I have 64 bit version installed.

What else can I do?

**Follow UP:** So after the reply from (MrVaykadji - Thanks :) ) here are the results:

```
speed@testing:~$ arch 
x86_64 

speed@testing:~$ free -h | awk 'NR>0{arr[$2]}END{for(i in arr) print i}' | grep G 
2,9G

speed@testing:~$ sudo lshw -class memory | grep GiB  
[sudo] password for speed: 

size: 4GiB 
    size: 2GiB 
    size: 2GiB
```

It all seems to me to be 64bit system. What now?!

Please... Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: With the informations you added, we now know that your system is a 64 bits, that he uses only 3GiB of RAM but sees 4GiB (2x 2GiB) installed on the motherboard. That's a start: the problem is software-related, nothing to do with your hardware apparently. :)

Comment: Hi. I mite add that windows 7 did "see" the full 4GB of RAM before I formated and installed Ubuntu.

So... what now?

What can I do or change to try and sort this out?
Thanks

Comment: Please, add `dmesg` output.

Answer (score 3):

To see what architecture (32bits=x86 or 64bits=x86_64) you have installed :

```
arch
```

To see the total RAM (in GB) the software-part of the system detects :

```
free -h | awk 'NR>0{arr[$2]}END{for(i in arr) print i}' | grep G
```

To see the total RAM (in GiB) the hardware-part of the system detects :

```
sudo lshw -class memory | grep GiB -m 1
```

To see each RAM slot and what does your system sees installed in each* :

```
sudo lshw -class memory | grep GiB
```

*note : GB is gigabyte (1000³ bytes, decimal table) and GiB is gibibyte (1024³ bytes, binary table). It's OK to see exactly how much RAM you have in GiB and it also is OK to see a little less than "real" RAM you have in GB. Just saying.*

---

In this example, I use my own system, which :

- it has a 64bits (x86_64) architecture.
- it uses 7,8GB (= 8GiB) of RAM
- it has 8GiB installed on the motherboard
- it has 4x 2GiB installed (2GiB per slot)

*note: "taille" means "size" in french.*

[image: output example]

---

This should help you at first, I'll come back if I think of something else. Hopefully it will be a real answer, this is at most a tip to verify your sayings and what your system sees.

Answer (score 0):

When you overclock RAM it might not be seen properly.I had to slow down the timings a bit to use all of my RAM. Hope this helps someone overclocking.

Use memtest though when you overclock. You dont want stability issues.