# i dual booted 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8.1 on laptop with 4 gb ram..it now shows 2gb in either operating system

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 14.04

I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Windows 8.1 on a laptop with 4 GB ram... I noticed that my computer was much slower after the dual boot, so I checked the ram in Ubuntu and it showed 2 GB... and then I checked the ram in Windows and it showed 2 GB...

It looks like my 4 GB ram got divided into 2 parts : 1 for Windows and 1 for Ubuntu.

How can I make both Windows and Ubuntu use the full 4 GB ram when they are respectively running ? I have searched for solutions and this seems to be a problem with quite a lot of people, and I did not find any answer or solution in any of the searches that I made. Please suggest a solution.

hi these are some additional details..
i went to bios and it shows that i have 2gb ram only...
i put ubuntu 14.04 on a usb stick again and restarted my computer...during re-installation, the ubuntu 14.04 recognizes that you have windows and ubuntu 14.04 and provides an option to erase the existing ubuntu 14.04 and re-install ubuntu 14.04....i did that...the newly installed ubuntu 14.04 still has the same problem..
but during re -install there is this option something else..and it has settings for swap space etc..but i dunno how to do it...

p.s i took screenshots, but i dont know how to upload it here..there is no option here to
upload images..could anybody please tell me how to do it...

Comment: Look at my answer here to check you hardware's RAM, and please edit your question with the additionnal informations that it will provide : http://askubuntu.com/questions/425652/ubuntu-13-10-64bit-version-only-shows-2-9gb-of-ram/425664#425664

Answer (score 1):

This actually looks like a stick of ram has vanished!

When either Linux or Windows is running on bare hardware, they will see all of the hardware of the system, did you open your system in order to install a new HDD for the ubuntu install?

Windows and Linux will both probably be seeing the same stick of ram, please update your post with infomation on anything which you may benefit us to help you, including the answers of the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You have try to check on the two sticks of  RAM.
Power down PC completely. Unplug the PC. Remove the RAM and clean the contacts with contact cleaner. Do not touch the contacts. Reseat the RAM. Reboot and check if it helped.
If not, then remove one stick of RAM and try to boot. If it did not then remove that stick and insert the other stick and boot. This might tell you which RAM stick is bad or which RAM port on the motherboard is bad. Good luck.